# Deploy com GIT x Deploy com Gulp

Tags: git, front-end, versionamento, deploy, gulp

Eu ainda não consegui entender sobre qual o melhor deploy de um site. Explico a forma como estou fazendo:

### GIT

- Iniciei um repositório local
- Hospedei meu repositório em algum serviço como GitHub/Bitbucket
- Entrei no servidor via SSH e **clonei** o repositório direto desse serviço
- Sempre que eu atualizo o site no meu PC (local), dou um PUSH novamente pro GitHub/BitBucket, entro na hospedagem do site via SSH e dou um PULL pra atualizar os arquivos.

Dessa forma eu consigo manter tudo versionado sem precisar de FTP e acho rápido. Mas essa é uma prática correta de se fazer deploy com GIT?

---

### GULP

Já com GULP a coisa muda um pouco. Há duas pastas: **dist** que é a pasta de "produção" ou deploy, pelo que entendi; e a pasta **app** que é a pasta em que estou trabalhando, pasta de desenvolvimento.

Se eu for fazer deploy com GIT, há como CLONAR somente a pasta DIST no servidor via SSH? E se for fazer deploy com o próprio GULP via FTP, seria uma prática correta?

---

Eu sei (ou acho que sei) fazer deploy das duas formas, mas queria entender uma prática mais correta de se fazer isso. Uso GIT pra versionar meus projetos e queria usar GULP, mas não sei se devo versionar as duas pastas (dist e app).

Comment: Então Israel, no caso do gulp a pasta app é onde se encontra o source do projeto e é ela que vc deve versionar a pasta dist não tem necessidade de versionamento já que é o deploy, ela vc só precisa publicar mesmo...

Comment: Você pode usar um hook post-receive do git para gerar o dist usando o gulp assim que receber no servidor. Assim você consegue manter o dist fora do versionamento e diminui a carga de transferência de arquivos.

Comment: Adicionalmente, é possível configurar um webhook no github pra atualizar o seu servidor automaticamente. Assim você não precisa acessar o server via ssh toda vez que alterar o código.

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o deploy com git você pode melhorar ele seguindo os seguintes passos:

**1. Adicionar um repositório bare no servidor de produção.**

Esse repositório "bare" não contém os arquivos da cópia de trabalho. Basicamente é o conteúdo da pasta .git no lugar da cópia de trabalho.

```
   $ git init --bare ~/git/projeto.git
```

**2. Adicione o hook post-receive**

Este scrtipt é executado quando o push da máquina local for concluído e move os arquivos para um lugar. Ele ele está em project.git/hooks/ e é chamado de 'post-receive' (se não existir crie). Você pode usar o vim para editá-lo ou criá-lo. O script verifica se o ramo correto é empurrado (não implementando um ramo de desenvolvimento por exemplo).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Um exemplo de script para o hook post-receive que atualiza os arquivos de um diretório.

TARGET="/var/www/projeto"
GIT_DIR="/var/git/projeto.git"
BRANCH="master"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
     # Apenas checa se o branch enviado é o master (ou qualquer outro ramo que você gostaria de fazer o deploy)
     if [[ $ref = refs/heads/$BRANCH ]];
     then
          echo "Referencia $ref recebida. Atualizando ${BRANCH} branch para  produção..."
          git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
     else
          echo "Referencia $ref recebida. Nada foi feito: Somente a ${BRANCH} branch pode atualizar este servidor."
     fi
done
```

**3. Adicione o repositório remoto no seu repositório local**

```
    $ cd ~/caminho/para/copia-de-trabalho/
    $ git remote add producao ssh://usuario@servidor/var/git/projeto.git
```

**4. Faça um push para o servidor de produção**

Agora você pode realizar um push do branch master para o servidor de produção:

```
$ git push producao master
```

E toda vez que precisa realizar um deploy para o servidor de produção, basta fazer um push. Espero ter ajudado.